# Radio button group with button at the right end

Tags: jquery-mobile, controls, radio-group

I am new to jquery, I stuck with one problem

Possible Duplicate

[jQuery Mobile buttons on same row as controlgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908906/jquery-mobile-buttons-on-same-row-as-controlgroup)
But the provided solution does not worked for me.

I am trying to make a radio control group using jqm with a button on right side. I am creating the radio buttons . like this:-

```
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="privacylistdata" 
                data-theme="c" class="ui-grid-a">

                <label for="Setting1">Setting1</label> <input class="privacytype"
                    type="radio" name="privacy" id="Setting1"
                    value="Setting1"> 

                  <label for="Setting2">Setting2</label> <input
                    class="privacytype" type="radio" name="privacy"
                    id="Setting2" value="Setting2">

                   <label for="Setting3">Setting3</label> <input
                    class="privacytype" type="radio" name="privacy"
                    id="Setting3"
                    value="Setting3">
            </fieldset>
```

I like to add a button on right most side of each radio control group in same row like this.

[image: Adding button at right end of control group]

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to have to controlgroups side by side using a table:

```
    <table class="privacylistdatatable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="privacylistdata" data-theme="c">
                    <label for="Setting1">Setting1</label>
                    <input class="privacytype" type="radio" name="privacy" id="Setting1" value="Setting1">
                    <label for="Setting2">Setting2</label>
                    <input class="privacytype" type="radio" name="privacy" id="Setting2" value="Setting2">
                    <label for="Setting3">Setting3</label>
                    <input class="privacytype" type="radio" name="privacy" id="Setting3" value="Setting3">
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td class="rightColumn">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="privacylistdataBtns" data-theme="c"> 
                   <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Icon only</a>
                   <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Icon only</a>
                   <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Icon only</a>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then use some CSS to make things line up nicely:

```
.privacylistdatatable {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.privacylistdatatable td {
    padding: 0px;
}
.privacylistdatatable .rightColumn {
    width: 24px;
}
.privacylistdatatable fieldset {
    margin: 0;
}
#privacylistdata .ui-radio label {
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
}
#privacylistdataBtns .ui-btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-left: 0 !important;
}
#privacylistdataBtns .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
#privacylistdataBtns .ui-last-child .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9.5px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/pytz8Ldx/)**

Comment: Thanks ezanker,This was what I needed :)